# How to make iexfianace stock take an input from a form data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, wtforms

I am trying to get stock price from iexfianance. When i try to run this i get `ValueError: Please input a symbol or list of symbols`.How do i make `s=Stock()` to take input from the form? I Tried to change the input into a string but that didn't work its already a string. Please Help!!

```
class InvestmentForm(Form):
    stockSymbol = StringField('Stock Symbol', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=2, max=5 ,message='Please Enter Correct 
    symbol')])
    allotment = FloatField('Allotment', validators=[InputRequired()])
    finalSharePrice = FloatField('Final Share Price', validators=[InputRequired()])
    sellCommision = FloatField('Sell Commision',validators=[InputRequired()])
    initialSharePrice = FloatField('Initial Share Price', validators=[InputRequired()])
    buyCommission = FloatField('Buy Commission', validators=[InputRequired()])


@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form = InvestmentForm()
    userInput = form.stockSymbol.data
    s = Stock(userInput)
    print(s.get_price())
    return render_template('home.html',form=form)
```

Comment: What exactly is **Stock** in **s = Stock()**? a function? What is she doing? how did you write it?

Comment: it takes a stock symbol as Stock('MSFT').Its a function from iexfinance https://pypi.org/project/iexfinance/

Comment: Class names should be CamelCase i.e `InvestmentForm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to submit the form input data, add a `submit = SubmitField()` in your `InvestmentForm`. Make sure you pass `request.form` in `form = InvestmentForm(request.form)` or just use [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#validating-forms).

```
class InvestmentForm(Form):
    submit = SubmitField()

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = InvestmentForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        user_input = form.stockSymbol.data
        s = Stock(user_input)
        print(s.get_price())
return render_template('home.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for the error is that you try to extract `form.stockSymbol.data` in a `GET` request when user input is not available. Try changing your code, so it distinguishes between `GET` and `POST`, like so:

```
from flask import request
@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form=investmentform()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        userInput = form.stockSymbol.data
        s = Stock(userInput)
        print(s.get_price())

    return render_template('home.html',form=form)
```